# Function sequences in $C[0,1]$ using infinity norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I am working on the space of continuious function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ with the infinity norm ($ \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|$). My question is the following

Is it possible to construct a sequences of continuous function $f_{n}: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $\mid f_{n}(x)\mid$  converges to $0$ but the sequence  $\{f_{n}\}_{n}$ does not converges to 0 in the normed space $C^{\infty}[0,1]$ with the infinity norm.

Comment: Which norm are you using on $C^\infty[0,1]$ (or you want to say $C[0,1]$?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** consider $f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
nx &\text{ if } x\le \frac 1n\\
2 - nx &\text{ if } \frac1n x\le \frac 2n\\
0&\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Prove that $f_n(x>0)$ converges to 0, and as $f_n\left(\frac 1n\right) = 1$.